# Allowable characters in a web form

Tags: forms, web, input

I have always been confused that which characters should be allowed in which field of a web form. I am just finding a list like First Name can have A-Z and a-z etc. Can anyone please tell me the same thing for all the fields for the form below? [Please note that the website is UK-based so the UK standards we need to follow].

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would there be a limit on how a person can call himself or the place he lives in? Post code changes between countries and regions. Any of those fields might be in different languages in the future, too.

In short, there's no reliable way to determine allowable characters, you just need to make sure that if I decided to call my kid `Robert'; DROP TABLE Students; --`, that it doesn't have negative effects on your code. Bobby tables is a valid name.

Comment: What about Phone, Email?

Comment: You would verify an email by sending an email anyway. If the email is invalid it will be caught later on (Right????). As for phone, there are so many different options, validating it correctly is nigh impossible. Decide on a format you like on your own, and enforce that.

Comment: @asma while an email address has a defined structure, most validators out there are wrong, (e.g. not supporting international domains or other flaws). As _Second Rikudo_ already said a better way is to test by sending or with an initial SMTP _hand shake_.

Comment: The following is a valid email address: `dont.tell+me_im_invalid@something.long.here.ninja`. Many validators will get it wrong.